# How do I overwrite a text file line by line using StreamWriter WriteLine in c#

Tags: c#, streamwriter

As part of my c# learning, I have a simple game on a console application. I have now added a text file to record the top score. It has 4 lines, date, number of attempts, time in minutes and additional time in seconds. The text file is part of the project solution, and although I don't specify the full path, I can read the file with StreamReader and output the lines without any trouble. But if I have a new top score, and I wish to overwrite the values in the text file, nothing is happening. The text file remains unmodified.

I have tried using StreamWriter. It feels somewhat intuitive to use StreamReader ReadLine to bring the data into the application and StreamReader WriteLine to output. But the output piece is not working. For my sins, this is my code. There are some similar queries on stackooerflow, but I've not found a solution that appears to fit my query.

```
if (newBestScore== true)
{
    DateTime dateToday = DateTime.Now;
    string dateString=dateToday.ToShortDateString();
    string currAttempts=CurrentAttempts.ToString();
    using (StreamWriter newTopScore = new StreamWriter("TopScore.txt"))
    {
        newTopScore.WriteLine(dateString);
        newTopScore.WriteLine(currAttempts);
        newTopScore.WriteLine(timeTaken.Minutes);
        newTopScore.WriteLine(timeTaken.Seconds);
        newTopScore.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: You're using a relative path. Are you sure you're writing to the correct file? When debugging the current directory is `bin\Debug\net...`

Comment: You are telling us that the file _TopScore.txt:_ is part of the project. Then if you click on it and look at its properties, what is the value of _Copy File to Output directory_?

Comment: Instead of using StreamReader/StreamWriter I would suggest using a serialization library that takes a .Net object and converts it to a string or bytes. [Json.Net](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm) is one example of a popular library.

Comment: For your specific question it is fairly likely that you either use different paths in different places, or run into an exception that is swallowed. But it is impossible to tell from the provided example. It may also be useful to use `Path.GetFullPath(...)` to confirm what file will actual be used.

Comment: @Ralf: The default behaviour of StreamWriter with that constructor is to create the file if it does not exist or to overwrite the file if it does exist.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. I should have said that the code compiles fine. I can force the new best score and that code runs fine, only the writing to the text file is not working but no errors are showing up. I can confirm the file is in the bin\debug folder associated with the project. Under the properties tab for the file, Copy to Output Directory is set to Copy Always. I played with the other settings. The code would not compile on Do Not Copy. Copy If Newer was no different to Copy Always. Apologies Jonas that serialization libraries are beyond me at the moment.

Comment: Have you checked where your current directory is? For example when you are debugging and your are currently stepping through the shown method when you look at "Environment.CurrentDirectory" is it your expected folder? If not your file has been written to the current folder named there as you are using a relative path (only the file name without a path) here.

Comment: @Paulf your correct deleted my comment as i couldn't edit it anymore to state that i'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I'll not fix your problem, but I'll tell you how you can fix all problems of this sort by yourself in the future.

Download [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) and add a filter for your application, like so:

`Process Name`, `contains`, `<myapp>.exe` then `Include` and then add this filter by pressing the Add button.

[image: Process monitor]

Then start recording and look for `TopScore.txt` and see in which directory it looks for that file. You can use the find dialog for that (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>):

[image: Find dialog of process monitor]

Then have a look at the full file name of that file, so you know where it it being written. You can even right click and choose "Jump to ...".

Understand what a working directory is. The file will be written in the working directory if you didn't provide a full path.

Why go this way? This way proves that you have a problem independently. You don't change the source code. Whenever you change the source code and e.g. add diagnostics code like `Console.WriteLine(Path.GetFullPath(...));`, problems may disappear.

Comment: I appreciate the tip, thanks. In this case I know where the file is. It is in the bin/debug folder for the application. I can also read it fine with StreamReader.